# Exclude models based on a value from another model with no foreign key

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-queryset

I have the following schema

```
class Review(models.Model):
    comment_id = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_id = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField()
```

**NOTE 1** there is no Foreign Key beside the fact that `Review` and `Comment` models have exactly the same `comment_id`

**NOTE 2** there is one-one/unique relation (only one occurrence of the `comment_id` will exists at each table)

I want to make a select query to fetch all the `Review` models that their relative `Comment` model **IS NOT OLDER** than 10 days.

Comment: Why did you not use a `ForeignKey` in the first place?

Comment: It is legacy code and changes to DB schema are prevented...

Comment: But declaring that as a OneToOneField in a Django model does *not* entail any changes to the schema.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: well a FK will make a FOREIGN KEY constraint, for a OneToOne it will probably add a UNIQUE constraint as well. But I agree that in terms of columns/... you can use a `to_field`, and it will not use a different field type.

Comment: the CI/CD does not automatically run DB migrations. That means that if I made a change to the Schema I have to report it and someone run these migrations twice (staging/production env)

Comment: @dios231: well my own experience is that bad modeling usually results in a lot of trouble (inefficiency, checking constraints actively, inconsistent states, etc.). So actually I'm personally more in favor of fixing models, then trying to "work around" that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I can not understand why the FK is so major issue for a solution...

Comment: @dios231: because of referential integrity, and because Django ships with a lot of programmers convenience for relations. If one of my collegues did not enforce relations, I think that would be a very major red flag (and eventually reason to fire such person, if they persist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Option 1: add a relation (*strongly advisable*)

I strongly advice to ue a `OneToOneField` here, since this will enfore referential integrity, and check uniqness. You can construct such models with:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    comment = models.OneToOneField(
        'Comment',
        to_attr='comment_id',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This does not only enforces integrity, it makes querying more convenien, we can simply query with:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta

Review.objects.filter(
    comment__uploaded__gt=(timezone.now()-timedelta(days=10)).date()
).values('comment_id')
```

## Option 2: query with nested query

In case this is completely impossible, yo can use:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta

comments = Comment.objects.filter(
    uploaded__gt=(timezone.now()-timedelta(days=10)).date()
).values('comment_id')
```

then we can fetch the corresponding reviews with:

```
Review.objects.filter(
    comment_id__in=comments
)
```

The above will generate a query that looks like:

```
SELECT review.*
FROM review
WHERE review.comment_id IN (
    SELECT U0.comment_id
    FROM comment U0
    WHERE U0.uploaded > 2019-09-06 00:00:00
)
```

Comment: I would like to combine these two queries into one but I am not sure if this is possible. Option 2 works so I mark it as the accepted answer. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Given your models you can do something like this:

```
comments = Comment.objects.filter(uploaded > (the_days_specified)).get(comment_id)
reviews = Review.objects.filter(comment_id__in=comments)
```

Comment: (I assume that you would write values_list instead of get). The problem with this solution is that the count of `Comment` models are about 800.000+. And your first query will be very slow. I want a solution to make this filtering into one query

Comment: I think that comments = Comment.objects.filter(uploaded > (the_days_specified)).get(comment_id) is bad query, maybe comments = Comment.objects.filter(uploaded__gt =(the_days_specified)).get(comment_id=comment_id) is the correct way of filter when you need filter by "greater than" and needs the pair "key = value"

Comment: @dios231: A queryset is, with `.values()` not evaluated, so you never really pull the `comment_id`s into memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the raw query like:

```
mydate = timezone.now()-timedelta(days=10) ##you need import timezone.now and timedelta
query = '''SELECT * FROM app_review as r 
                      INNER JOIN app_comment as c 
                      ON r.comment_id = c.comment_id
                      WHERE c.uploaded>{date}'''
Review.objects.raw(query.format(date=mydate))
```